# Pegar 12 meses de tabela data para o group by e continuar pegando os dados de outra tabela com data variavel, utilizando LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

A minha tabela 'a', possui um determinado numero de datas, de janeiro a dezembro.

A minha tabela 'b', é uma tabela calendario de 2014 a 2100.

O meu objetivo é dar um group by de janeiro a dezembro,  entretanto na minha tabela 'a' é variavel e pode existir não necessariamente até dezembro.

[Exemplo Real do problema [DB Fiddle]](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rKaJ2aafzp8KaeSxLESjKA/1)

```
SELECT
    a.data_tb1
FROM tabela_com_data_variavel AS a
GROUP BY MONTH(a.data_tb1) 
-- O resultado é variavel não pega 12 meses porque só olha as datas da tabela com datas variavel
```

Como estou tentando fazer puxando a data de outra tabela com todas as datas

```
SELECT
    a.data_tb1
FROM tabela_com_data_variavel AS a
LEFT JOIN (
           SELECT b.data_calendario 
           FROM tabela_com_dados AS b
           ) ON a.data_tb1 = b.data_calendario 

GROUP BY MONTH(b.data_calendario )
```

Ou seja como pegar 12 meses dessa tabela auxiliar para o group by
e continuar pegando os dados da tabela_com_data_variavel, utilizando LEFT JOIN ou de outra forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

```
SELECT 
MONTH(b.fulldate) AS MES_DATE, YEAR(b.fulldate) AS ANO_DATE, 
COUNT(a.demissao) AS adm_1

FROM dates AS b

LEFT JOIN cadastro_funcionarios_connect AS a
    ON MONTH(a.demissao) = MONTH(b.fulldate)
    AND YEAR(a.demissao) = YEAR(b.fulldate)

GROUP BY

MONTH(b.fulldate), YEAR(b.fulldate);
```

Lembre-se, traga sempre a tabela que contenha mais dados e faça um **LEFT** na que tenha menos dados, você pode concatenar os valores também para unificar o **MONTH()** com o **YEAR()**. Ajuste o código conforme a sua necessidade.